# How can I programmatically detect if MSMQ has been installed on the current system?

Tags: c++, msmq

How can I programatically detect if MSMQ has been installed on the current system?

I am using C++, but answers in other laguages could still be helpful.

(VS2008, WinXP and up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply ask COM to create an instance of the `MSMQQueueInfo` object. If it succeeds you know that MSMQ is installed.

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <mqoai.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto error = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

    if (FAILED(error))
    {
        wcout << L"You've got bigger problems" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        CComPtr<IMSMQQueueInfo> info;

        error = info.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MSMQQueueInfo));

        if (SUCCEEDED(error))
        {
            wcout << L"MSMQ is installed" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a pointer for C# [here](http://www.ms-news.net/f2437/howto-detect-programmatically-if-msmq-installed-5028989.html) - call a method to enumerate the queues and check the error code.

> The way I'm doing it now is to
>   try-catch the
>   'GetPrivateQueuesByMachine' method,
>   that will throw an exception with the
>   'MessageQueueErrorCode.ServiceNotAvailable'
>   error code.

Another option would be to install the MSMQ WMI Provider [here](http://yoelarnon.wordpress.com/2008/04/02/the-msmq-wmi-provider/) and query for MSMQ object instances on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You also can check for the existence of the registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ`. If the key exists, MSMQ is installed.

Answer (score 0):

[How to tell if MSMQ is installed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-tell-if-msmq-is-installed.aspx)